# Visual Studio expression containing a term named "by" cannot be evaluated in the watch window

Tags: c++, watch, visual-studio-debugging

Consider my C++ code below:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int by = 10;
    printf("%d\n", by);

    int bx = 20;
    printf("%d\n", (by + bx));

    return 0;
}
```

which works fine. The funny thing is with the "by" variable. If I try to add a watch for a simple expression that contains by, the result will be CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated.

For example, on a breakpoint on `return 0`, if I add the following watches I get the results mentioned:

```
by : 10
bx : 20
by + 5 : CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated
bx + 5 : 25
by + bx : CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated
(by) + bx : 30
by + (bx) : CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated
bx + (by) : CXX0014: Error: missing operrand
```

This happens on VS2010, VS2008 on multiple computers.

So, more out of curiosity, what is happening with "by"? Is it some kind of strange operator? Why doesn't bx get the same treatment?

(I've tried google on this but it is quite difficult to get some relevant hits with terms like "by")

Comment: file a bug report, I have it here too

Comment: Ahhh, my hopes are that this is some kind of hidden feature :D, not just an ordinary bug.

Comment: The "missing operand" one is especially eyebrow-raising.

Comment: Parna, your wish has been granted :-) See our friendly discussion below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're seeing here is the C++ Expression Evaluator's implementation of the `BY` operator.  Your use of the expression `BY` is being interpreted as an operator instead of a local variable.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56638b75.aspx

A lot of discussion has gone into whether or not this behavior is a bug or by design.  Unfortunately that can only be truly answered by the people who implemented the feature.  As dissatisfying as it is for this scenario there could be valid reasons why this was explicitly done (costs of disambiguating comes to mind).  Or this could simply be an oversight of the implementor.  Again only they know the answer.

If this does feel like a bug to you then please do file a bug on connect.  This is the best way to get your opinion heard and very likely the team has never received any feedback on this behavior (could not find any in my searches).

Comment: "This behavior is by design." As I said somewhere else, just another Microsoft cock-up. What a stupid design decision!

Comment: @TonyK enabling a whole set of debugger functionality at the cost of not being able to debug a very specifically named variable ... I'd call it a win.  Yes they could've done more to shim this scenario but given the extreme ease of the work around it's still a win.

Comment: Work-around? What work-around? The work-around would have been to require that Assembly-Language expressions be preceded by a special character. '@', for instance. Is that a shim? I'm not familiar with the term.

Comment: By the way, what is your 'extremely easy' work-around? Are you suggesting that programmers rename their variables so that they can examine them in your debugger? If so, is this bizarre requirement prominently documented?

Comment: Restating work-around twice doesn't make your argument stronger, just longer.  And yes the work around is to rename the variable to not conflict with an operator recognized by the expression evaluator.

Comment: @JaredPar: I am lost for words. (And that doesn't happen often.) I write debuggers myself, and when users report annoying behaviour, I fix it. But then I'm not Microsoft.

Comment: @Tony Without talking to the people who implemented this it's impossible to say if it is a bug or by design. Given that it's been this way for 5+ years without changing my instinct is to say they considered it "by design" or "bug which didn't meet the bar".  My *personal opinion* is that it's a bug but once again only the people in charge of the feature *know*

Comment: @JaredPar: If it's a bug, why are you defending it tooth and nail? (I don't think it's a bug, I think it's a design cock-up. As you know.)

Comment: Thank you JaredPar. I don't believe it's a bug, in the light of the documentation revealed, it's clearly a feature of the debugger. The fact that I wasn't aware about it, it definitely doesn't make it a bug. Damn it, I hoped for this one not to be a bug!

Answer (score 9):

Intrigued by this, I did some digging. From [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2t7ahxk.aspx), we see that the native C/C++ expression evaluator in the debugger handles Assembly-Language expressions; following the [Assembly-language link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56638b75.aspx), we discover that BY is short for BYTE in an an Assembly-Language expression. So just another Microsoft cock-up

Comment: Rolled back the edits and deleted comments so there's no discontinuity between the two.  Enjoy the badge though!  :)

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: I hope you don't mind if I call you a boring old fart.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Your lawn? You deleted my comments, I didn't delete yours! Some of them were pretty snappy too, if I remember right.

Comment: @TonyK: Sure, snappy they were, but they were all about your choice of words and not about the question being asked/answered here.  Such distractions (particularly the profanity-laden ones) are often purged.

Comment: I bet you put on a necktie before you log in here :-)

Comment: @TonyK: I never wear them.  I do log in from work though, and I work in exactly the kind of place that will block sites if they're perceived as too "unprofessional."  I'd hate to get blocked, so I do what I can to keep the atmosphere on SO as professional as possible.  I hope you understand.

Comment: @TonyK: No, I won't get fired, the site will get blocked at the firewall.  Did you want to see some of the other moderator tools in action?

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: I think you overstepped here, but... I was not rude, maybe a little sarcastic...  The root of the question in my comment was based on all the people I see pitching or defending their companies product without exposing their affiliation.  I find that annoying at best.  If you've been here a while and pay more than minimal attention, you eventually find out that JaredPar is an MS employee...

Comment: @JimR: There was a long list of comments here yesterday that I deleted partly because they were *all* off the point of the question, but mostly because many of them used strong profanity.  They all seemed to revolve around TonyK's use of various forms of the phrase "cock-up."  If I inadvertently deleted a legitimate comment that you made then I apologize.  I probably just misunderstood it in this context and thought it was part of the "cock-up" discussion.  Feel free to repost it.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: You've removed the context...  A lighter hand would be appreciated in the future.  Not to mention I've forgotten what I wrote. :)

Comment: @JimR: I'm afraid it's my fault. I did rather goad poor Bill (to the extent that he suspended me for 24 hours!).

Comment: @TonyK: Forgotten :), I don't see you as at fault unless you were really flaming and I missed it.  I think this was a typical Microsoft minimally tested screwup/cockup/f-up and they deserve to be chastised for it.  I also think the moderation around here is a little too heavy handed but I've only been around here 2 months or so.

Answer (score 4):

What you're running into is the debugger's ['memory operator'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/99dwf401.aspx):

> In native C++, debugger expressions do
>   support the following additional
>   operators:
>
> - The context operator ({ }) to specify the context of a symbol.
>     For more information, see Context Operator (C/C++ Language
>     Expressions).
> - Memory operators (**BY**, WO, and DW) to access memory. Memory operators
>     have the lowest precedence of any
>     operator. The memory operators are
>     useful mainly in debugging
>     assembly-language code.